# Custom time-dependent greeting on User does not show correctly when used with Live Agent

Tags: formula, liveagent

We have a custom formula on User that's like this:

```
IF(HOUR(TIMEVALUE(NOW())) < 18, "Good morning", "Good evening")
```

This evaluates correctly on the User object.  When we reference this field in the Chat Agent Configuration (the Auto Greeting part) it seems that it can't evaluate expressions based on a formula, only concrete record references.
Has anyone here successfully created a such a dynamic greeting for a Live Agent user?

Comment: This should be doable with an apex class of bot. See [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_greet_customer_lex.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula fields are not directly available as merge fields in the auto greeting

You can try the approach of using an Einstein bot to just provide the greeting message.

Step 1: Created an auto launched flow
Here ReturnsTrueFalse is the formula condition[image]

Created an assignment variable FORMULAOUTPUT that set value of ReturnsTrueFalse to FormulaVar

Step 2:Created a bot with action type as "Flow" and used the "FormulaVar" as variable "FlowOutput"> Then created rules to display the greeting > Then chat transferred to an agent
[image]
Final outcome was
[image]

As an alternate appraoch, you could get a parameter from the site like “Morning / Evening” using [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_elseif) via the PreChat API(using the embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails) , and then pass this to value field, use it in the bot as context variable.

Recommend reviewing [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_greet_customer_lex.htm)

Comment: Thanks Swetha, this is exactly what I was searching for, namely the bot cookbook!